# MySQL prefix index in django?

Tags: mysql, django, indexing

I have a CharField(max_length=260) in a utf8-general-ci MySQL DB. The column is too long to be fully indexed so I want to use the prefix index feature of MySQL.

"Indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an index prefix length"
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Is there a way to do this in django? What is the best way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other options except executing SQL query directly.

Read this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly